# How can I show "ALL" in a multi-valued parameter if the user selects all?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

At the moment, my multi-valued parameter is getting values from a dataset.

How can I show "All" essentially if the user selects all?

It is currently showing all the values that are being selected. I just want an "All" to be shown in the event that the user misclicks and deselects one. That way, the user would not that the query is not on ALL values. The parameter list is quite long.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the dataset populating the available values for your parameter to insert an artificial "ALL" option and then change the query logic in your report datasets to check for "ALL" being passed as the parameter instead a a group of selected values.

There is an blog posted here that describes this in detail:
http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2013/12/18/the-select-all-parameter-option-ssrs/

To give a quick summary, if your query for parameter available values is:

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName FROM dbo.Product
```

then this changes to

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName FROM dbo.Product
UNION ALL
SELECT -1, 'ALL'
```

Then if your main report query is something like:

```
SELECT SaleDate, SaleAmount FROM dbo.Sales WHERE ProductCode IN (@Product)
```

this becomes

```
SELECT SaleDate, SaleAmount FROM dbo.Sales 
WHERE 
   ProductCode IN (@Product)
   OR
   -1 IN (@Product)
```